# HTML/Url decode on multiple times encoded string

Tags: c#

We have a string which is readed from web page. Because browsers are tolerant to unencoded special chars (e.g. ampersand), some pages using it encoded, some not... so there is a large possibility, we have stored some data encoded once, and some multiple times...

Is there some clear solution, how to be sure, my string is decoded enough no matter how many times it was encoded?

Here is what we using now:

```
public static string HtmlDecode(this string input)
{
     var temp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
     while (temp != input)
     {
         input = temp;
         temp = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
     }
     return input;
}
```

and same using with UrlDecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably the best approach honestly. The real solution would be to rework your code so that you only singly encode things in all places, so that you could only singly decode them.

Comment: sure, if the world were perfect, and all developers uses standards, it would be much easier. because if I will check whether string is encoded only once, I have same problem as in question, just placed elsewhere. maybe I forgot to notice in question, I read not my own page, but feeds from different sources.

Comment: Seems pretty amateur to double or triple encode. But your solution will certainly work to solve the problem if it is truly out of your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be decoding html strings correctly, with multiple checks.

However, if the input HTML is malformed, i.e not encoded properly, the decoding will be unexpected. i.e bad inputs might not be decoded properly no matter how many times it passes through this method.

A quick check with two encoded strings, one with completely encoded string, and another with partially encoded yielded the following results.

`"&lt;b&gt;"` will decode to `"<b>"`

`"&lt;b&gt` will decode to `"<b&gt"`

Answer (score 1):

In case this is helpful to anyone, here is a recursive version for multiple HTML encoded strings (I find it a bit easier to read):

```
public static string HtmlDecode(string input) {
    string decodedInput = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);

    if (input == decodedInput) {
        return input;
    }

    return HtmlDecode(decodedInput);
}
```

`WebUtility` is in the `System.Net` namespace.